# HTML Purifier Coding Help?

Tags: php, mysql, htmlpurifier

I read the http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-youtube.html doc, but I still can't figure out where to put the code to allow object, param and embed tags and `Use experimental features` with my htmlpurifier. Can someone please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Add this.

```
 $config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
 $config->set('HTML.SafeEmbed', true);
```

To this.

```
 require_once '../../htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

 $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
 $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
 $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Strict'); // replace with your doctype
 $config->set('HTML.SafeObject', true);
 $config->set('HTML.SafeEmbed', true);
 $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

 $about_me = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify($_POST['about_me']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML.SafeObject eats a lot of memory I do not recommend you:

http://support.chamilo.org/issues/1450